# Add script dynamically in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field

I save a banner script into an hidden field.

```
script = $('#myHiddenField').val();
```

I want to display the banner into a div but the banner overwrites the whole page. Everything disappears and I can see only the banner.

```
$('#divBannerContent').html(script);
```

Suggestions?

Comment: My bet it has a document.write in the script you are adding and that will be impossible to deal with.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Can you provide result of `$('#myHiddenField').val()` ?

Comment: Could you just eval it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the script after the document loads?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    script = $('#myHiddenField').val();
    $('#divBannerContent').html(script);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    script = '<pre>' + $('#myHiddenField').val() + '</pre>';
    $('#divBannerContent').html(script);
})
```